# 1.9 Problematic URL Rewrite Management

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

Looking into the telemetry of Magento and came across something a bit odd.

Fudged up URL Rewrite Management and cut my server load time in 1/2
https://eliteshoppercentral.com//about.html
Notice how i added a "/" to redirect to cms page without "duplicating" entry. 
What would cause this to result in 1/2 of avg load time? Cache or No Cache, results are consistent.
[image: ReWrite Management]

Comment: Possibly because it is not handled through most of Magento's standard routing so it can jump straight to URL rewrites. You could enable the Varien Profiler to find out more about it, the frontend routing system is well covered by it.